# Distributing resources with golang

Tags: go, resources, relative-path

I'm developing a library that contains a resource file, specifically an email template. The file is on `<project_root>/templates/email.html`.

I'm having a hard time referencing this file from the `.go` sources, since it's hard to resolve a relative path. So far the options I found are:

- use `$GOPATH`: this comes with the issue that some dependency managemente tools may redefine `$GOPATH` and break
- use a custom env variable: works but it forces the user of the lib to add the variable.
- inline the template on a string: it's ugly.

Does anyone have a better alternative? I'd rather not use 3rd party libs just for this but if you know one feel free to point it out so I can read the sources and see how they do it.

Thanks

Comment: Consider embedding the email template file directly into your binary: see [github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata](https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata)

Comment: Inlining resources is IMHO the best way to go when you develop a Go library. This way, resources are totally transparent. Embeding the template into the binary will directly impact those who use your library and need to compile it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The most common technique is to embed the resources so all you have to do is distribute the binary.

[This list](https://github.com/avelino/awesome-go#resource-embedding) of Go libraries has a list of libraries that do resource embedding:

> - [esc](https://github.com/mjibson/esc) - Embeds files into Go programs and provides http.FileSystem interfaces to them.
> - [fileb0x](https://github.com/UnnoTed/fileb0x) - Simple tool to embed files in go with focus on "customization" and ease to use.
> - [go-bindata](https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata) - Package that converts any file into managable Go source code.
> - [go-embed](https://github.com/pyros2097/go-embed) - Generates go code to embed resource files into your library or executable
> - [go-resources](https://github.com/omeid/go-resources) - Unfancy resources embedding with Go.
> - [go.rice](https://github.com/GeertJohan/go.rice) - go.rice is a Go package that makes working with resources such as html,js,css,images
>     and templates very easy.
> - [statics](https://github.com/go-playground/statics) - Embeds static resources into go files for single binary compilation + works with
>     http.FileSystem + symlinks.
> - [vfsgen](https://github.com/shurcooL/vfsgen) - Generates a vfsdata.go file that statically implements the given virtual
>     filesystem.